# How to compare two fingerprint templates of R305

Tags: algorithm, fingerprint

I used R305 finger sensor to scan my finger and generate to templates.

templates finger1:

> {'ef', '01', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '02', '00', '82', '03', '01',
>   '54', '26', '00', '00', 'e0', 'fe', '80', '7e', '00', '00', '00',
>   '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00',
>   '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00',
>   '00', .......................}

templates finger2:

> {'ef', '01', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '02', '00', '82', '03', '01',
>   '51', '21', '00', '00', 'f8', '3e', 'e0', '0e', 'e0', '02', 'c0',
>   '02', 'c0', '00', 'c0', '00', '80', '00', '80', '00', '80', '00',
>   '80', '02', '80', '02', '00', '02', '00', '02', '00', '06', '00',
>   '06', '80', '06', '80', '0e', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00',
>   '00', '00', ...................................}

How to use **C**, python or Java to external compare two templates?

Comment: thanks you for your comment, i tried internal compare R305 (upchar to R305 via uart and compare) but, it very slow because i have 1000 fingerprint. i want to external compare to improve speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match fingerprints, you need a specific algorythm, please read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition

You could do it with an AFIS server : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Automated_Fingerprint_Identification_System

Here some providers of AFIS solution:

http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
http://au.nec.com/en_AU/solutions/security-and-public-safety/biometrics/afis-fingerprint-identification-features.html
http://www.innovatrics.com/products
http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/afis/
http://www.m2sys.com/automated-fingerprint-identification-system-afis/

If you want a OpenSource algo, [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/) have a SDK for fingerprint recognition: [NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm).

It could be downloaded [here](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Comment: thank you so much. because i think module R305 had processing 80% of the work, it scan finger and generate to array character, so i think i should just find algorithm compare 2 array. but it is seem impossible.
perhaps i must read all of link you send to do it. thanks you

Comment: @LaurentY do you know which format the R305 output follows? Also the providers you have mentioned only work on images, or even on templates? I'm very interested in this topic, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RohinGopalakrishnan SourceAFIS has the ability to compare ISOTemplates. But the problem I face is that the R305 output is not being recognized as an ISO Template by SourceAFIS

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to write your own algorithm . R305 provides it's own algorithm to compare two templates. Go through the R305 specification and implement it.

Comment: R305 has fingerprint comparison which is inbuilt to the sensor. The question is, he wants to compare the templates from outside the sensor.